# php - check in constructor if class function is called by class instance

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to do something like this one:

```
class conditional
    {

        function __construct()
        {
            if (launch() is called) {
                //return True 
                //function is called by class instance
            }else{
                //return False
                //launch() is not called
            }
        }

        public function launch(){
            echo "function is launcher";
        }
    }
```

I am trying to use a condition in `class constructor` to know if the class function is called by class instance or object as `$class_instance->launch()`. If the `function` is not called by `class instance` then it should run return `else` condition.

Comment: `$class_instance->launch()` doesn't trigger `$class_instance::__construct` method as you expect in the code above

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest So is there any other possible way to implement this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want to do (nor I understand why would want to).

The constructor will run when you create the instance, before you are able to call any of the instance methods. Unless you have a way to delve into the future and know at instantiation time if any of the instance methods will be called later on, no dice :)

But you can do something that more or less looks like that using the `__call` magic method, even if probably doesn't make much sense in most scenarios.

E.g., a very simplified implementation:

```
class Magical {

   public function __call($method, $args) {

       switch($method) {
          case "launch":
             echo "magical launch() was called\n";
             $this->magicLaunch();
             break;
          default:
             throw new \Exception("Method not implemented");
       }
  }

  private function magicLaunch() {
      echo "magic!";
  }
}


// this is the only point where the constructor gets called
$magic = new Magical();

// since the launch method doesn't exist, the magic method __call is invoked
$magic->launch();
```

Outputs:

> magical launch() was called
>
> magic!

Comment: Yes this is the thing that I am finding... Thank you